# System.FormatException

Tags: c#, sql

i have a problem with my sql statement, first of all i hope devloped a generic method that update my base with a generic paramteres so 
the iNT idSELECTED is :

```
int idSELECTED = Convert.ToInt32(TypeItemsSelection.idTypeItem);
```

but i don't know how i can select my id where my id=idselected with a generic statement

```
public static int GetId(string Table, string NameiD, int IdSelected)
    {
        Int32 id = IdSelected;
        Int32 genericId=0;
        MySqlConnection connection;
        string connectionString = "server=localhost; user id=root; password=WPF2020; database=imitems";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT (" + NameiD + ") from  " + Table + "where @name=@select", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Text);
        command.Parameters["@name"].Value = NameiD;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@select", IdSelected);

        MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

thank you for your attention

Comment: Why are you combining concatenated strings and parameterized queries to begin with? You don't even appear to be using the id variable at all here.

Comment: `Table + "where @name=@select"` - Missing space - but more importantly you cannot use params for column names, the query still makes little sense as it stands.

Comment: where do you get this **System.FormatException**?, where do you call this **int idSELECTED = Convert.ToInt32(TypeItemsSelection.idTypeItem);**?.
As a tip, you can try to compose your query with a string.format and avoid all the **command.Parameters.Add**

Comment: Okay I will hope creat the statement liké this "select ID from table where id=selectid "but my id and selectid in the pramatre of methode

Comment: you can't use a parameter for a column name. Use parameters for variables. For the column name you'll have to concatenate it. Be sure to verify that value is acceptable before you concatenate it (e.g. using a whitelist of accepted column names, for instance), to guard against injection attacks.

Comment: Give me a exemple plz @Adyson

Comment: well, your query is just like `"where " + NameiD + " =@select". The difference is, before you do this, you check that the value of `NameiD` is an ok value, e.g. it's one of a set of column names you accept (perhaps you keep these in an array, or another DB table, it doesn't really matter, the important thing is to check that `NameiD` is one of those values). Otherwise someone could potentially try an attack like the one in the cartoon here: http://bobby-tables.com. If you check for acceptable values before running the query, no-one can try and input something malicious.

Comment: i will try it and after i will tell u the result

Comment: thank the problem is : espace betwen the table and where LOL OMG